# Homework: C Programming - Structures and Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, structure

My assignment requires the use of the following linked list structure:

```
      struct studentNode {
        int     id;
        char    *fname;
        char    *lname;
        int     programs[x];
        int     labs[x];
        int     exams[x];
        int     percent;
        double  grade;

        struct  studentNode *next;
      };
```

My problem is, the arrays for programs, labs and exams are being loaded from a file and are to be variable lengths.

I tried using a pointer to the array, however whenever I updated the array for a new student it would replace the scores for everyone in the linked list.

I've tried going over this with the instructor and he tells me to google it. :(

So far, I haven't had any luck and it's beyond the scope of what our book covers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code you've already written.

Comment: Was having trouble with the display, it's up now.

Comment: When you say _whenever I updated the array_, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I create the array int scores[] = {90, 95, 100} and then update the array scores[0]=80... Per the answer below I think I need to allocate new memory for it.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe:

You need to create a new object for each item in the array.

so first you create something to hold the first item (like a pointer to the first item). Then as you load each item, create new studentNode  and then add it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the same array for all students. You need to allocate a separate array for each student.

You can either statically allocate a fixed number of elements in a 2d array:

```
int progs[Num_students][x];
```

In this case you will need to point each studentNodes array to the correct array(for each student).

```
studentNode1.programs = progs[studentNumber];
```

Or allocate some memory on the heap for each student.

```
studentNode1.programs = malloc(sizeof(int)*x);
```

Comment: I believe the instructor wants us to allocate additional memory. I'll try your second suggestion.

Comment: don't cast the return value of malloc in C. it's unnecessary and it can silence compiler warnings which you might want to see. (the exception is in polyglot C/C++ code, where the cast is required.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each `studentNode` isn't sharing the same `programs`, `labs`, etc arrays.  In  addition to creating the `studentNode`, you have to create the arrays within them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is referring to how to specify the size of the programs, labs, and exams arrays.

Instead of storing the array in your struc, keep a pointer to your array. Then, after you have built your program array outside of your structure (using malloc if necessary) reassign your node.program pointer to that array.